# SemanticUI implementation doesn't work till the end

Tags: semantic-ui

I tried to include the SemanticUI "Multiple Search Selection" (https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) in my Bootstrap based script.

This is how it should look like:
[image]

This is how it looks like:
[image]

After excluding bootstrap it looks like this:
[image]

This is why I suspect Bootstrap on interfering. Any ideas of how to find the error?

Comment: what version of bs are you using? I suspect it will be bs interfering with the `.label` style

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. `.label` sounds promising. Is there a way to leave everything as it is and only overwrite or delete the bootstrap css for my dropdown?

Comment: @y0hami, do you have an idea?

Comment: No, you will have to manually remove bootstrap label styles, from my experience it is a pain to use two frameworks in the same project. I would consider picking bootstrap or semantic and sticking to it.